# Add iptable rules by a pod inside itself and also in the worker node

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a requirement where I'll deploy a pod and when it comes up I need to add some iptable rules inside the pod.
At the same time, I need to add some iptable rules in the worker node on which the pod is running.

If I use "hostNetwork" option for the pod, the iptable rules which I need to add in the pod will also get added to the worker node.

How can this be achieved, where the pod itself adds iptable rules inside the pod as well as in the worker node.

Answer (score 3):

Not recommended. ⛔

Basically, the kube-proxy and the network overlay generally heavily use iptables to make things happen in Kubernetes. Adding your own iptables could work but you would have to watch everything Kubernetes does and make sure anything you do doesn't conflict.

There is no specific tool that would help manage all of the iptables that Kubernetes creates along with the ones you create. This would only work at the node level. There isn't such a thing as adding iptables at the pod level.

You could use some of the networking objects like [Network Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/) to restrict traffic or if you are using Calico you can use a more [advanced version of it](https://docs.projectcalico.org/reference/resources/networkpolicy).

Another option is just to have an external firewall that restrict some traffic to your nodes in your Kubernetes cluster.

✌️

Comment: hi, "There isn't such a thing as adding iptables at the pod level." i used to think so before , but some case broken it recently
i research chaos-mesh, and use the nsexec to try a case, i create a demo pod on node A and execute `nsexec -n /proc/xxxxxx/ns/net -l iptables -L` found there is different with node , it's empty  
------
when i try to add a iptable rule, it is work well, only for this pod
------
are there any articles to introduce this? is netfilter isolation by namespace ?
------ tools: 
https://github.com/chaos-mesh/nsexec
node linux kernal : 4.14
k8s version: 1.16